# how to get value from select case when query in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
select     `event_attendees_mapping`.`attendees_status_id`
            FROM
                `event_attendees_mapping`
            WHERE
                ((`event_attendees_mapping`.`event_schedule_id` = 1)
                    AND (`event_attendees_mapping`.`employee_code` = 'TJU_741')                    
                    )
```

using this query i  am able to get value  i have converted in case and when condition .

```
 select case     
           when (select     `event_attendees_mapping`.`attendees_status_id`
            FROM
                `event_attendees_mapping`
            WHERE
                ((`event_attendees_mapping`.`event_schedule_id` = 1)
                    AND (`event_attendees_mapping`.`employee_code` = 'TJU_741')                    
                    )  )then    1

                    else
                    0
                    end
```

but here i am getting Error Unknown table 'event_attendees_mapping' in field list while from query i am able to get value  please tell me where am doing wrong please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select     CASE WHEN `event_attendees_mapping`.`attendees_status_id` = ????
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END as new_Col
FROM `event_attendees_mapping`
WHERE `event_attendees_mapping`.`event_schedule_id` = 1
  AND `event_attendees_mapping`.`employee_code` = 'TJU_741'
```

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '????                 THEN 1                 ELSE 0            END as new_Col FRO' at line 1  Error is comming

Comment: I should replace the ???? with whatever attendees_status_id you want to test it against. But I've no idea what exactly you want as a result.

Comment: @sagi  please suggest mw why this Error coming

Comment: :S, because you need to replace `????` with what ever value you want to compare to. Answer me this -> When does the value should be `1` and when should it be `0` ? @MhanazSyed